# jQuery DataTables createdRow not changing row color

Tags: jquery, datatables

Have a datatable setup:

```
            var table = $('#items').DataTable({
                    'pageLength': tablelength,
                    'lengthMenu': [[10, 15, 20, 25, 50, 1000, -1], [10, 15, 20, 25, 50, 1000, 'All']],
                    'ajax': {
                        'url': '/LoadItems/',
                        'type': 'POST',
                        'data': {
                            'itemtype': itemtype,
                            'displayunits': displayunits
                        },
                    'createdRow': function (row, data) {
                        if (row.Unit == '1') {
                            $(row).removeClass('even');
                            $(row).removeClass('odd');
                            $(row).addClass('unit1');
                        }
                    },
                },
                'columns': [
                    { 'data': 'Id', 'name': 'Id' }, // 0
                    { 'data': 'PermitNumber', 'name': 'PermitNumber' }, // 1
                    { 'data': 'Unit', 'name': 'Unit' }, // 2
                    { 'data': 'Status', 'name': 'Status' }, // 3
                    { 'data': 'EnteredDate', 'name': 'EnteredDate' }, // 4
                    { 'data': 'EquipmentId', 'name': 'EquipmentId' }, // 5
                    { 'data': 'Reason', 'name': 'Reason' }, // 6
                    { 'data': 'ClearedDate', 'name': 'ClearedDate' }, // 7
                    { 'data': 'Fill', 'defaultContent': '' } // 8
                ],
                'columnDefs': [
                    { 'visible': false, 'targets': [0] },
                    { 'sortable': false, 'targets': [8] },
                    {
                        'render': function(data, type, row) {
                            return '<span class="detail" id="' + row.Id + '" title="' + row.Id + '">' + row.PermitNumber + '</span>';
                        },
                        'targets': 1
                    }
                ],
                'order': []
            });
```

Does not seem to be executing the class adds and removes as when I view the page source via Developer tools, the new Classes do not appear.  I tried removing the if statement as well so that it would fire on every row, but still nothing.

I have tried the rowCallback as well, and nothing seems to be working.

Comment: The indenting shows that `createdRow` is under the `ajax` options instead of the dataTable options.  `createdRow` works fine if you put it in the correct place, eg: https://jsfiddle.net/5gzoh0v2/

Comment: Protip: add a `console.log("createdRow")` in your callback (or various other debugging methods) and check the console to see if it's actually firing - if it's not firing, then no amount of changing the content to add/remove classes/ifs will have an impact.

Comment: Thanks for both those tips.  I completely missed that I was dropping the code inside the ajax call.  Now its doing the highlighting.

Answer (score 0):

The comments to my question pointed me in the correct direction to track down and solve my issue.  I had the code inserted inside a function rather than out on its own.